# Which is the most comprehensive way to check applied KBs to a Windows machine?

Tags: powershell, wmic, qfe

I am using Powershell to run a status of a list of KBs and see if they are applied or not.

I have found a few ways and I have seen inconsistencies with the numbers they are reporting. Which is right?

You can check `SYSTEMINFO` and get a list of hotfixes. You can also use the `Get-Hotfix` cmdlet, which is an alias for `gwmi Win32_QuickFixEngineering` or you can use `wmic qfe list` (**WMI-C**LI **Q**uick**F**ix**E**ngineering **L**ist).

So, why am I getting different numbers when I do a quick count?

*i.e.* `(Get-HotFix).Count` and `(wmic qfe list).Count`

Using those two returns 153 and 310, respectively.

What gives? Why does it return different values? Are all of the applied KBs not listed in the `Get-Hotfix` cmdlet?

Before anyone asks, yes, I have restarted the machine and I haven't applied any since it was restarted and updated. That is Day 1 stuff...

Comment: This is a clear question, obviously well-researched, about an area of Windows that is poorly documented. I have zero idea why you are being down voted, so have an up for balance.

Answer (score 1):

WMIC has obscure blank lines which might be muddying the waters a bit. Here's simple, not very good, parser for wmic qfe (Windows 10 so who knows if it'll transpose).

The hope is that you can compare the lists.

```
$qfe = wmic qfe list brief | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Where-Object { $_.Trim().Length -gt 0 } | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Description = $_.Substring(0, 17).Trim()
        HotFixId    = $_.Substring(30, 10).Trim()
    }
}
Compare-Object (Get-HotFix) $qfe -Property HotFixID -IncludeEqual
```

So is that enough? No, not really. QFE is great but indicative only. I'm trying to remember the circumstance that invalidates it. I'll come back to this.

Comment: In lieu of an update, because it feels like it's going to come to me some time over the weekend. We encountered a problem during an AD RAP where QFE was not reporting everything because of something one of the admins had done. We had to use something else to assess patch levels. Vague, sorry, if I remember properly...